# How to execute all process parallel inside for loop in winforms C# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

[image]

I have created on function which will split single fine into multiple file. For example i have one file which contain 100 pages now i would like to create new files for every 15 pages, it means it will create 7 files each file has 15 pages. (100/15 = 7)

Now my problem is i have implemented logic for splitting files using **Thread**, **ISynchronizeInvoke** and **delegate** to smooth process and user experience. It is working aspected, but *i would like to perform each split in parallel or simultaneously instead of one by one process*.

This code has been written in Splitter.cs file
I have written following code:

```c#
#region Private Variables
private NotifyProgress _notifyDelegate;
private Thread _thread;
private ISynchronizeInvoke _synchronizingObject;
//this is the definition of the progress delegate - it defines the "signature" of the routine...
public delegate void NotifyProgress(int TotalFiles, int ProcessFileIndex, int TotalPages, int PageIndex, string Size);
#endregion

private void splitFiles()
{
    //Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
    PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(PDFFile);
    Reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
    Reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
    for (int f = 0; f < Files.Count(); f++)
    {
        List<int> Pages = Files[f].Pages;
        string FileName = (f + 1).ToString();
        string folderPath = Path.Combine(OutputFolderPath, GeneratedFilesFolder);
        string gereatedPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format(FileNameFormat, FileName));
        //This method will create folder if the path doesn't exist
        CreateFolder(folderPath);
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;
        Document currentDocument = new Document();
        PdfSmartCopy pdfWriter = null;

        bool bIsFirst = true;
        long _size = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < Pages.Count; p++)
        {
            NotifyUI(Files.Count(), f, Pages.Count, p, _size);
            if (bIsFirst)
            {
                bIsFirst = false;
                currentDocument = new Document(Reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                pdfWriter = new PdfSmartCopy(currentDocument, new FileStream(gereatedPath, FileMode.Create));
                pdfWriter.SetFullCompression();
                //pdfWriter.CompressionLevel = PdfStream..BEST_COMPRESSION;
                pdfWriter.PdfVersion = Reader.PdfVersion;

                currentDocument.Open();
            }
            _size += pdfWriter.CurrentDocumentSize;
            importedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(Reader, Pages[p]);
            pdfWriter.AddPage(importedPage);
        }
        currentDocument.Close();
        pdfWriter.Close();
        FileInfo _f = new FileInfo(gereatedPath);
        NotifyUI(Files.Count(), f, Pages.Count, Pages.Count - 1, _f.Length);
    }
}

private void NotifyUI(int TotalFiles, int ProcessFileIndex, int TotalPages, int PageIndex, long Size)
{
    //this method will fail because we're not telling the delegate which thread to run in...
    object[] args = { TotalFiles, ProcessFileIndex + 1, TotalPages, PageIndex + 1, CalculateFileSize(Size) };
    //call the delegate, specifying the context in which to run...
    _synchronizingObject.Invoke(_notifyDelegate, args);
}
```

This code has been written in Form.cs file

```c#
private void DelegateProgress(int TotalFiles, int ProcessFileIndex, int TotalPages, int PageIndex, string Size)
{
        if (splitter != null && PDFSplitter.TotalPages > 0)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                int IndividualProgress = PageIndex * 100 / TotalPages;
                lstFiles.Items[ProcessFileIndex - 1].SubItems[1].Text = Size;
                TextProgressBar pb = (TextProgressBar)lstFiles.GetEmbeddedControl(3, ProcessFileIndex - 1);
                pb.Text = string.Format("{0:00} %", IndividualProgress);
                pb.Value = IndividualProgress;

                int OverallProgress = ProcessFileIndex * 100 / TotalFiles;
                ProgressStripItem statusProgrss = (ProgressStripItem)tsStatus.Items[3];
                statusProgrss.TextProgressBar.Value = OverallProgress;
                statusProgrss.TextProgressBar.Text = string.Format("{0:00}%", OverallProgress);

                if (OverallProgress >= 100 && IndividualProgress >= 100)
                {
                    tslblMessage.Text = "File has been split successfully.";
                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(tslblMessage.Text + "\nDo you want to open split files folder?", "Split Completed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        OpenSplitFilePath();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < lstFiles.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        lstFiles.RemoveEmbeddedControl(lstFiles.GetEmbeddedControl(3, i));
                    }
                    lstFiles.Items.Clear();
                    splitter = null;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with implementing using thread but couldn't get result for parallel process! Could you please give me a hint where is i wrong. Thanks

Comment: what version of the .net framework are you on?

Comment: If you read/write them all to the same hard drive, chances are that the parallel route is going to go a lot slower than processing them in sequence...

Comment: i am using .net framework 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [**Parallel For loop**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx)? Here's a simple example.

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => 
{
    //What you would like to do simultaneously.
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);
});
```

If you ran try building and compile this simple code, you would notice that the output will be something like this.

```
8
4
5
7
2
3
9
1
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be achieved by parallel For Each. Refer the following link to know how to use parallel for each. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx